# Mongoose aggregate query to filter value from the ref collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, lookup

I have 2 collections as follow:

**event**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61f272dd1fac703fec69105a"),
    "eventActivity" : [  
        ObjectId("61f76703196ea94bd43fa92e"),
    ]
}
```

**event-activity**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61f76703196ea94bd43fa92e"),
    "activity" : ObjectId("61f2a69bfe99e07db083de50"),
}
```

Based on the collections above, **event** has `eventActivity` field which refers to **event-activity** collection. I'm trying to filter the event by the value of `event-activity.activity`.

So if for example my filtration selection has activity in an array `['61d6b2060d6fe32d9853ad40', '61f2a69bfe99e07db083de50']`, it will return the event. If the filtration selection has activity id `['61d6b2060d6fe32d9853ad40']`, it should not return any event as there is no event with that activity id from **event-activity**

I can't really understand how the aggregate lookup work but I tried this and it doesn't work.

```
event.aggregate([
    {"$lookup":{
        "from":"event-activity",
        "localField":"activity",
        "foreignField":"_id",
        "as":"event-activity"
     }},
     {
         "$match":{
             "event-activity.activity":{
                 "$in":["61d6b2060d6fe32d9853ad40","61f2a69bfe99e07db083de50"]
              }
          }
      }
])
```

I referred to the [manual here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Or can it be done by `find()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

- you can use lookup with pipeline and put the match inside
- if the lookup result is empty you can remove or keep the document based on your needs, with something like this
  `{"$match":{"$expr":{"$ne":["$activities", []]}}}`

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70930023-m)

```js
event.aggregate(
[{"$lookup":
  {"from":"event-activity",
   "localField":"eventActivity",
   "foreignField":"_id",
   "pipeline":
   [{"$match":
     {"activity":
      {"$in":
       [ObjectId("61d6b2060d6fe32d9853ad40"),
        ObjectId("61f2a69bfe99e07db083de50")]}}}],
   "as":"activities"}}])
```

Comment: Hi thank you. I will test it out.

Comment: Hi again, thank you for your codes. I tested it out and if I understood it correctly, the second query to remove is actually just removing the lookup documents from the join right? But it is still returning the event? My goal here is to totally not returning the event if the lookup is also empty. Something like in SQL query (not sure if you are familiar with it) if the join field value is empty, it will not return anything.

Comment: yes i thought you want this but i wasnt sure, thats why i said that you can use `{"$match":{"$expr":{"$ne":["$activities", []]}}}` if you want, to remove the even complelty if lookup was empty, you can add this stage after the lookup stage in the pipeline. `{lookup ..} {match ..}` Try it i think you want [this](https://cmql.org/play/?q=1643902895912)

Comment: Ah I see, I think I implemented the query wrongly. Now I see your 2nd example and that is what I need. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly you can use this aggregation query:

This query uses a `$lookup` with a `pipeline` where the result is given by a match with an `$in`. So, the join will return the values where the `event-activity.activity` is in the array `event.eventActivity`.

```
db.event.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "event-activity",
      "as": "activities",
      "let": {
        "ea": "$eventActivity"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [
                "$activity",
                "$$ea"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WuYx3miwTfC) where I've used integers as `activity` to see easier the join.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to write the sample query but this isn't what I am looking. The `event.eventActivity`  is not referring to `event-activity.activity`. Instead, `event.eventActivity` = `event-activity._id` and the `event-activity.activity` is referring to another collection but I don't really need to lookup for that collection. That's why I did not include it in my question. But I need to filter the event based on the value of `event-activity.activity`. Hopefully my elaboration doesn't confuse you :)